# Need help to handle ORM/ODM bundle size for lambda NodeJS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, orm

Currently, I have a total of 50 lambda functions and all of them have TypeORM and Typegooes in there, It makes each lambda bundled size always +1-2MB just for ORM/ODM. it makes the team suffer every time deploys (~ 5min) and the client keeps complaining that the lambda function cold starts too long (~600ms).

For a longer goal, I think I need to change something to handle this downside. I don't know which one is better or some other architecture is better to handle this:

- Keep everything there and don't try to do anything. Microservice architecture is the best.
- Refactor all ORM/ODM to a separate lambda/path (/user, /service) and one lambda handle all DB query for that path. this is Monolithic architecture:

  - Pros:

    - All other lambda bundled sizes will only be ~ 20KB/each. I just need to create 1 lambda to handle ORM, 1 lambda to handle ODM, and a DB connection for each path (/user, /service) (I don't think putting everything in 1 lambda is the best use case).
    - Reduce cold start to only 1 time/path, not each time lambda is triggered.
  - Cons:

    - 1 error can make all paths fail

Is there any way besides what I mentioned is better for this?

Comment: Could you consider use lambda layer for ORM/ODM?

Comment: Im using esbuild for bundle now, i am considering to use lambda layer, but client happiness still my first priority, because if i use layer, each func still have to cold start ~ 600ms